# Probability coding confusion?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider n coding machines M1, M2, . . . Mn producing binary codes 0 and 1. The machine
M1 produces codes 0 and 1 with respective probabilities 1/
4
and 3/
4
. The code produced by machine Mk is
fed into machine Mk+1 which may either leave the received code unchanged or may change it. Suppose
that each of the subsequent machines change the code with probability 3/
4
.
Given that final produced code is 1. What is the probability that the machine M1 produced code 0.

I have little confusion, that can we neglect all machines from M1 to Mn-2 , and consider only following four cases:
M0 start with 0,then Mn-1 receive number as 1 or 0
M0 start with 1, then Mn-1 receives number as 1 or 0
to compute the probability of machine Mn to output 1?

Comment: Well, why not test your theory with $n=3$ or $n=4$?

Comment: Initially, I misinterpreted the problem.  I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, lulu caught another error which I have also corrected.

Comment: see problem's addendum, which I just added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As lulu's subsequent comment indicates, I made a bad error in my answer, which I have now corrected.  Normally, I would consider leaving the erroneous analysis for contrast.  In this case however, I think that it would simply add confusion.

---

Assume that code starts at 0, **before** it is encoded by machine M1.

Let A denote the event that M1 kept the code at 0. 
Let B denote the event that M1 changed the code to 1.

Let C denote the event that machines M2 through Mn had an even number of changes.

Let D denote the event that machines M2 through Mn had an
odd number of changes.

There are two mutually exclusive ways that an odd number of changes occurred.  Either events A and D both occurred, or events B and C both occurred.

Let $p = 3/4$ and let $q = (1-p).$
Then the desired probability is

$\displaystyle \frac{q \times P(D)}{[p \times P(C)] + [q \times P(D)]}.$

Let $m = (n-1)$.

For machines M2 through Mn:

Chance of $k$ changes is $f(k) = \binom{m}{k}p^kq^{(m-k)}.$

Then $P(C) = \sum_{k ~\text{even}} ~f(k)~$ and 
$P(D) = 1 - P(C).$

**Addendum**

One of lulu's subsequent comment focused on unwinding the even/odd probabilities.

Coincidentally, the following mathSE query, which occurred in the last 24 hours, generated an answer that seems relevant here.

[Prove monotonicity of combinatorial sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835634/prove-monotonicity-of-combinatorial-sum)

Comment: @lulu good catch thanks.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: That looks correct (+1).  I wonder, though, if there is anything one can say to unwind the even/odd probabilities.  After all, for large $n$, we can take $P(D)=P(C)=\frac 12$, regardless of the probability with which $M_i$ acts (well, assuming it doesn't just do one thing all the time.).  For small $n$, though, I'm not sure we can say much.

Comment: @lulu Normally, I would say yes, re examining Pascal's triangle on the even and odd rows, it is easy to conjecture odd coefficients vs even coefficients on the odd rows and similarly on the even rows.  **However**, $p=(3/4)$ instead of (for example) $p = (1/2)$ seems to throw a major roadblock into this type of analysis.

Comment: @lulu Considering that $p = 3q$, this *suggests* that the $p = (3/4)$ roadblock might be conquered via examining the coefficients of $(3 + 1)^{(n-1)}.$  My typical mathSE reaction to this type of situation is to not really care whether simplification is possible.  Ironically, I recently gave a valid answer that was awarded 0 points, while a subsequent answer used totally different analysis to indicate a dramatic simplification.  The other answer was awarded 5 points.  My reaction was **really**?

Comment: @lulu Extending my last note (and leaving these notes for others to read), if $m = (n-1)$ is odd, and $k$ is odd, then $\binom{m}{k}p^kq^{(m-k)}$ represents one group of odd possibilities, while $\binom{m}{m-k}p^{(m-k)}q^{k}$ represents its *counterpart* group of even possibilities.  Don't know what you could do with this though.  By the way, I certainly agree that as $m \to \infty$, chance of odd # changes $\to (1/2).$  Again, I don't know what you could do with that.

Comment: @lulu see problem's addendum, which I just added.