# Prove monotonicity of combinatorial sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I'm certain (from intuition and simulation) the following sum is monotonically decreasing in $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and monotonically increasing in $p \in [0.5, 1]$. But I don't know how to prove it. Here's the sum:

If $m$ is even:
$$    \sum_{k \mbox{ even}}^m \binom{m}{k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k}
$$

If $m$ is odd:
$$    \sum_{k \mbox{ odd}}^m \binom{m}{k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k}
$$

Help please?

Comment: Small world : user381027's answer also has relevance re the following : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834495/probability-coding-confusion/

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$ 1 = (p + 1-p)^m = \sum_{k=0}^{m}  {m\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k}$$
and
$$(1-2p)^m = (-p + 1-p)^m = \sum_{k \ even}^{m} {m\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k} - \sum_{k \ odd}^m {m\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k}$$

Hence
$$\sum_{k \ even}^{m} {m\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k}  = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + (1-2p)^m \right) \\ \sum_{k \ odd}^{m} {m\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{m-k} = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 - (1-2p)^m \right)$$

Now you can proceed from here.

Comment: I upvoted, very elegant.

Comment: Wow I didn't expect such a great answer and so fast, thanks a lot! While that's a minor part in a paper I'm working on, please PM me with your details so I can add you in the acknowledgments section.

Comment: Small world : your answer also has relevance re the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834495/probability-coding-confusion/